# drawImage (canvas) is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I want to draw multiple canvases on a single canvas using `drawImage()` method but it is not working 
**Code**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var context1= document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
    var context2  = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
    var context3  = document.getElementById("canvas3").getContext("2d");

    context1.font = "20pt Calibri";
    context1.fillStyle = "blue";
    context1.fillText("Hello ", 50, 25);

    context2.font = "20pt Calibri";
    context2.fillStyle = "red";
    context2.fillText("World!", 100, 25);

    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function() {
      context3.drawImage(context1.canvas, 50, 25);
      context3.drawImage(context2.canvas, 100, 25);
        };
  };

</script>
 </head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas1" class="canvas" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" class="canvas" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" class="canvas" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
</body>
</html>​
```

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/4xT2j/2/

Comment: Your images have no source. What are you expecting to see ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your images have no source. Add one if you want to see something.
The onload function cannot be called as long as you don't have a src.

And you must provide the image to the drawImage function :

```
 var imageObj = new Image();
 imageObj.onload = function() {
   context3.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 25);
   context3.drawImage(imageObj, 100, 25);
 };
 imageObj.src = "someFile.png";
```

If what you're trying to do is draw canvas1 and canva2 on context3, simply do all this outside the imageObj.onload function which is never called : http://jsfiddle.net/KCyvE/

**A precision following a question in comment :**

My code in the fiddle uses `context1.canvas`. This works because The context is an instance of [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D) and thus has a property named `canvas` which is a *"Back-reference to the canvas element for which this context was created"*.

Comment: I want to add canvases not any image

Comment: So don't create an ImageObj. If what you're trying to do is draw canvas1 and canva2 on context3, simply do all this outside the imageObj.onload function which is never called.

Comment: I added a fidlle to explain that you just have to remove the ImageObj and simply include the content of the onload.

Comment: @dystory        Excuse me, according to your code on the jsfiddle, 
I found this instrument:　"context1.canvas". What does this mean?
Please help me give me some references, I can't find any explanation on the htmlV spec and many other place rather than chrome developer's hint...

Comment: @Stallman I've edited my answer to answer your precise question, with a reference to the excellent MDN.

Comment: What if I want to draw one .jpg at a specific location on a canvas. (specifically a poker card)

Answer (score 1):

Your `imageObj.onload` function is somewhat wrong. This is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/4xT2j/3/

Please observe there isn't necessarily a reason to write canvas3 to an image object since it already is an image object.